# Unable to run WatchKit app when supports running without iOS app installation is unchecked

Tags: swift, watchkit

I get the following error when trying to run my WatchKit app:

Please try again later.
This app has the ITSWatchOnlyContainer key set in its Info.plist, which identifies it as a shell app surrounding a Watch-only app; these are not installable.

I checked the Plists, there is no ITSWatchOnlyContainer entry.

Strangely enough the watch app starts if I check off: supports running without iOS app installation.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I dont remember exactly, as it was 5 months ago. But I think the problem was the target type I was using.

There are two different types of watch targets. Watch app for iOS app, and watch app. I had to use watch app for iOS app

Answer (score 0):

If you added a watch project into your iOS existing app. This might be the cause of the problem.

To fix this one:

1. Check for `WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier` in `Info.plist` located in `WatchKit App` Folder. If it does not exist, add it and the value for this should be the bundle identifier of your ios app.
2. In `Info.plist` located in `WatchKit Extension` folder, replace `App is only available as a standalone watchOS app` to `App can run independently of companion iPhone app`. Clean build & run. This should work after. If not, try closing and reopening the Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable **"Supports running without IOS App Installation"** options under **Targets(Watch app) -> General -> Deployment Info**

[image]